# Internet Explorer Caching CSV file

Tags: rgraph

I have created a chart which updates whenever a csv file  changes.
It displays correctly in Firefox but in Internet Explorer it caches
the csv file and only displays the correct value when the browser is
refreshed.
I have put the following into the header  but it still dosent work

Is there any way to stop Internet Explorer caching the file.

PJM

Comment: What header have you added?

Answer (score 0):

You could append a random query string to the URL:

http://www.foo.com/ajax/data.csv?cdcvhygvfghjguytdrtd

(changing it for each request)

Comment: Hi Richard the link you posted does not work can you please re post

Comment: It wasn't meant to work - it was an example of using a query string.

Comment: This is what I am using to call the CSV file    $(document).ready(func = function ()
        {
            RGraph.CSV('/OfficeThermostat.csv', function (csv)                                                                Where should I add the string could you please give me an example

Comment: Add the query string to the filename as in the example I gave.

Comment: Is it possible to add a time stamp to this string

Comment: It would be even better If I could add a filetime as then the page would only update when the file changes is this possible

Comment: Yes you can use a timestamp eg a unix timestamp: foo.csv?1397298984

Comment: Richard many thanks for your help and patience unfortunately my knowledge of coding  limited would it be possible to explain exactly how I would add this timestamps to the URL